# One function for two ID

Tags: jquery, joomla, scroll

I have a button with a scroll function, I would like to add another button with the same function. Can I do this?
this is php

```
<?php if($this->API->modules('cart')) : ?>
            <div id="btnCart" data-url="index.php?lang=<?php echo $lang; ?>&amp;tmpl=cart"><strong>Cart</strong></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

and this is jquery

```
// cart button
    if(document.id('gkPopupCart')) {
        var btn = document.id('btnCart');

        window.addEvent('scroll', function(e) {
            var scroll = window.getScroll().y;
            var max = document.id('gkMainWrap').getSize().y;
            var final = 0;
            if(scroll > 70) {
                if(scroll < max - 122) {
                    final = scroll - 50;
                } else {
                    final = max - 172;
                }
            } else {
                final = 20;
            }
            btn.setStyle('top', final + "px");
        });
```

Comment: yes , you can... but you have to use class for that... since ID should always be unique... and `document.id('gkPopupCart')` ... is this jquery ?? am i missing something here..

Comment: thx for the fast answer - i need duplicate only button like a "btnCart".

Answer (score 0):

```
 <? if($this->API->modules('cart')) {
 echo "<div id='btnCart' data-url='index.php?lang=$lang&amp;tmpl=cart'> 
       <strong>Cart</strong></div>";} ?>
```

i dont see why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: this is original code and he work perfect. i dont know how a duplicate this button. Sorry for my english.

Comment: this will make another button when the webpage containing it is put on a server and then retreived